# How to parse xml from column SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-parsing

I have SQL Server 2012 installed. There is a table called `channel_group` that has multiple records in the table.

```
[dbo].[CHANNEL_GROUP]
(
    [ID] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [NAME] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [REVISION] [int] NULL,
    [CHANNEL_GROUP] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)
```

From each record in the `CHANNEL_GROUP` column I need to get all values in the id tags for each channel tag for every record in the database.

What is the best way to parse this or query I could run that would be dynamic?

```
  <channelGroup version="3.4.2">
      <id>990b417d-27ae-4928-b4cc-cc010665615e</id>
      <name>Production</name>
      <revision>3</revision>
      <lastModified>
          <time>1490385251147</time>
          <timezone>America/New_York</timezone>
      </lastModified>
      <description></description>
      <channels>
          <channel version="3.4.2">
              <id>321439ff-46d6-4c3d-b1cd-ebc48d3c7fd2</id>
              <enabled>false</enabled>
              <revision>0</revision>
          </channel>
          <channel version="3.4.2">
              <id>c2d06aee-3031-4c6a-a3c1-23f7e96c971c</id>
              <enabled>false</enabled>
              <revision>0</revision>
          </channel>
      </channels>
</channelGroup>
```

Comment: Use XML methods https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-data-type-methods

Comment: If `CHANNEL_GROUP` column contains XML data then you should've declared it using `XML` data type instead of nvarchar ...

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,CHANNEL_GROUP varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'<channelGroup version="3.4.2"><id>990b417d-27ae-4928-b4cc-cc010665615e</id><name>Production</name><revision>3</revision><lastModified><time>1490385251147</time><timezone>America/New_York</timezone></lastModified><description></description><channels><channel version="3.4.2"><id>321439ff-46d6-4c3d-b1cd-ebc48d3c7fd2</id><enabled>false</enabled><revision>0</revision></channel><channel version="3.4.2"><id>c2d06aee-3031-4c6a-a3c1-23f7e96c971c</id><enabled>false</enabled><revision>0</revision></channel></channels></channelGroup>'),
(2,'<channelGroup version="3.9.9"><id>990b417d-27ae-4928-b4cc-cc010665615e</id><name>Production</name><revision>3</revision><lastModified><time>1490385251147</time><timezone>America/New_York</timezone></lastModified><description></description><channels><channel version="3.4.2"><id>SomeOtherID</id><enabled>false</enabled><revision>0</revision></channel><channel version="3.4.2"><id>AnotherID</id><enabled>false</enabled><revision>0</revision></channel></channels></channelGroup>')

Select A.ID
      ,Channel_ID= C.ID
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (Select XMLData=cast(A.CHANNEL_GROUP as xml)) B
 Cross Apply (
                Select [id]       = f.n.value('(id)[1]','varchar(50)') 
                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('channelGroup/channels') t(n)
                 Cross Apply t.n.nodes('channel') f(n)
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Channel_ID
1   321439ff-46d6-4c3d-b1cd-ebc48d3c7fd2
1   c2d06aee-3031-4c6a-a3c1-23f7e96c971c
2   SomeOtherID
2   AnotherID
```

Comment: the table contains multiple rows though. i would need to grab the row via query or some other method. This appears to hard code the value of one of the tables . Basically I would assume i need to query 1 table see how many rows there are then parse each of those to get the final list of records.

Comment: ok for example what if i have 1000 rows in the table. i wouldn't hard code them as it is above to parse them. I don't know how many rows i have in the table but it would need to be dynamic. basically i have  4 columns(id, name, revision, channel_Group) in the CHANNEL_GROUP table. overall what i need is to get the channel id which is located in the (id tag in the ChannelGroup tag.) this id will be a result column lets call it channelgroupID, every channelgroupID will have 1 or more channelID in them. The channelID will come from the xml structure which it appears you have solved that problem

Comment: ID NAME
29f37017-65d9-4052-954e-c3ca9f07136b Dev
967a1deb-8b47-4eb0-865a-adf6998667bd Group 1
990b417d-27ae-4928-b4cc-cc010665615e Production

Comment: @Villumanati the table variable (at)YourTable is just demonstrative.  This can be removed, and in the actual query, change  -- From  (at)YourTable  --  to From [dbo].[CHANNEL_GROUP]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139036/discussion-between-villumanati-and-john-cappelletti).